# Infinitive objective complement

Tags: infinitives, objects, complements

Why do some verbs can have “**to infinitive**” as *object complement*?

I found him **to be marvelous**

But others cannot:

I painted the house **blue**

And why do some verbs can omit the “to” in infinitive but some others cannot?

Can omit: I found him **(to be )** marvelous

Cannot omit: We want him **to be** a man

Comment: In your first example, the subordinate infinitival clause is not an objective complement, but a catenative complement of the catenative verb "find". Grammatically, the intervening NP is object of "find" and the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause. "Find can also take either and AdjP or an NP: "I find him very Intelligent / a fool".

Comment: "Paint" takes only AdjPs and NPs, while "want" takes NPs ("I want a new car") as well as catenative complements as in "I want to speak to Ed" / "I want them standing when the President enters".

Comment: The issue is not naming the grammar. The issue is being able to use verbs in the same categories. So, you might know what all that grammar means but if you don't do the memorizing work, you won't be able to use them correctly. I don't think learners need CGEL.

Comment: @Lambie Hey, how about we just call it *regência verbal* like everybody else does then? :)

Comment: I don’t know if this is right, after reading about the catenative rules I have some bold thought. So since the catenative would always follow either gerund or infinitive, even if there is a direct object, we can say that if it is a catenative, the complement object is ok to use infinitive like “I found it to be funny”. If this catenative verb can also function as a non catenative verb, then it would simply add a adj : I found it funny. And conversely, if the non catenative verb cannot function as a catenative at all, then infinitive would not be a choice, it won’t have a infinitive to follow.

Comment: This is one stone two birds. It solves the problem of why some can take infinitive as object complements(not catenative), and also why sometimes it would be omitted( catenative functions as non catenative)

Comment: @Gimletful You've got that wrong. Clauses **can't** be predicative object complements, as I said in my first comment.

Comment: But literally what is the difference? For me There are no difference in terms of meaning either it be a object complement or a catenative complement in these two sentences: 1 I found it funny 2 I found it to be funny.

Comment: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/object-complement/#:~:text=Transitive%20verbs%20that%20describe%20actions,consider%2C%20appoint%2C%20and%20elect.
And even here the verb “find” is cited as a verb that can use with a object complement.

Comment: Again, clauses **can't** be predicative (subject or object complements). The difference is grammatical, which is what your question is all about. Yes,"find" can be used in complex transitive clauses, but only with NPs and AdjPs as object or subject complement, **not** clauses. Is that clear now?

Comment: I see. Object complement: adj or noun. Infinitive is catenative complement, and it is called clause. But I wasn’t completely wrong in my previous answers after all.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: Subject complement: Our aim is to improve. [Our aim is something.] I was pondering a bit about the clause and the object complement thing. After I combed my knowledge, I realized something contradictory. As infinitive can function as a subject complement,  it should be able to function as object complement right? This is more like an intuition thing.

Comment: No: non-finite clauses can function as subject complement in the reversible specifying construction, as in your latest example. But they can't function as object complement.

Comment: Note, as I said before: in "I found him to be marvelous", the infinitival clause "to be marvelous" is not an object complement, but a catenative one. Grammatically, there is a big difference.

Comment: very cool, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The particular rules for what complements are required or possible for a verb are called its valency.  The rules are part of the grammar of the verb and may not have a logical reason.  Just as some verbs are transitive and some are intransitive, and you may not be able to logically work out that (for example) "search" is intransitive, you may not be able to work out that "find" permits an infinitive complement, but not "paint".

There can also be differences of meaning.  "I found him a man" and "I found him to be a man" are very different.  The first may be a verb with direct and indirect object, and the use of the infinitive has the effect of removing the ambiguity.

So there isn't a logical pattern to follow here, just the usual fact that syntax matters.  I would not say that "to be" is omitted in "I found him marvellous",  instead I'd say that "find" licences an adjective (phrase) as an object complement, but "want" does not licence a noun as an object complement.

Comment: But I'd have thought *most* instances of the verb ***to search*** are transitive, as in *We searched **the house***.

Comment: Okay, but it may be surprising that the object that is sought is not the direct object of "search".

Comment: Yeah - with "search" I think you *must* have a preposition before "the thing sought / searched for". But with near-synonymous "seek", I'm okay with prepositionless [*He sought the truth in books.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sought+the+truth+in%22)

Answer (score 0):

The verbs listed in 1) and 2) are taken from the British Council site.

1. Some verbs **take** a to-infinitive, others do not. You have to memorize them. Also, some can take a to-infinitive or -ing.

**verbs of thinking and feeling**:
choose
decide
expect
forget

hate
hope
intend
learn

like
love
mean
plan

prefer
remember
want
would like/love

verbs of saying:
agree
promise
refuse
threaten

others:
others
arrange
attempt
fail
help
manage
tend
try

verb + noun + to + infinitive [partial list]
**Some verbs are followed by a noun and the infinitive with to**:

*She asked him to send her a text message.
*He wanted all his friends to come to his party.

[See the full scoop for these English rules from the British Council (note that these verbs are the same in AmE](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/verbs-followed-infinitive)

2. I painted the house blue:

Here is what John Lawler said about a sentence like that:

[...] many sentence types fit into a single sentence frame like Subject Verb Object{?} Adjective, where the nature of the "Verb-Object" relation is subject to {?}, which is a very broad range.
For instance, from memory, some possibilities, with different predicates but the same *Subject Verb Object{?} Adjective* [italics mine] structure:
They shot him dead.
They found him alive.
They buried him alive.
*They *painted it black*.*
They called it black.
They named it "Peace Vermillion".

[language log_ Please see the full discussion](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2716#comment-89200)

Bear in mind: *All the verbs above are action (or active) verbs* in those examples. This is a common structure in English. SUBJECT + ACTIVE VERB+AdJ

However:
*We want him to be a man.

is an example of Verb + Noun [or pronoun] plus to-infinitive (see the British Council link above)
The verbs, among others, ask, want, advise, encourage take this pattern.

*I found him [to be] marvelous.

Find is an active (action) verb as it is followed by an object. And the *to be* can be omitted when the object, here a pronoun, is followed by an adjective.

Comment: Well to remember is the easier part, whether there is still certain logic behind it or not. The hard part is really  the grammar concerning the verb and infinitive as object complement. You have to first understand finite- non finite verbs, then to infinitive serves as different part of speech, then infinitive serves as subject predicate such as in linking verb sentence, then infinitive serves as object infinitive, only by then do I finally reached this far and asked this questions It feels just much easier to just remember words and it’s own rules

Comment: To choose between gerund and infinitive is relatively easier part I mean.

Comment: @Gimletful Have you studied French? There are verbs that take de and verbs that take à. You have to memorize them at first until you internatlize them.  [You might want to check your grammar in your comments. I'm sorry but it's full of mistakes.]

Comment: Well, I had some shallow experience with French, about a and de I mean. But since I didn’t delve deeper, that had been shelved. As for the mistakes, I learn by making them, or when I was driving.

Comment: @Gimletful Yes, you can learn by making mistakes. For example, Since I didn't dig deeper, I shelved that. Not had shelved. But that is a different question.